# How to return no result in search filter in react native

Tags: javascript, filter, react-native, react-native-ios

I am fetching my data from an API. I want that when I search something and if no data found then it should simply appear no result found in text format on the screen. But idk i am not being able to do that. Pls look at my code. thanks

filtering here:

```
  latestFeatured = value => {
    const latestFeatured = this.state.inMemoryLatest.filter(item => {
      let latestLowercase = item.speaker.toLowerCase();
      let latestTermLowercase = value.toLowerCase();
      return latestLowercase.indexOf(latestTermLowercase) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      latestuploads: latestFeatured,
    });
  };
```

return statement:

```js
<TextInput
    onChangeText={value => {
      this.latestFeatured(value);
    }}

    style={styles.textInput}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a conditional render, with:

```js
{ this.state.latestuploads && (
    <TextInput
        onChangeText={value => {
          this.latestFeatured(value);
        }}

        style={styles.textInput}
    />
)}
```

Here, the TextInput will only appear if `this.state.Latestuploads` it's not empty.
I don't really undertand your code entirely, but make sure you put the right state on the place of `this.state.Latestuploads` .